# Center bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to center my columns in bootstrap, so they are evenly distributed. I have set each column to col-lg-4, so that there are a maximum of 3 columns per row. So, if there are 5 columns, the rows should look like this:

```
col1      col2     col3
     col4      col5
```

If there are 4 columns, they should look like this:

```
col1      col2     col3
          col4
```

If 2, they should looks like this:

```
     col1      col2
```

I hope it makes sense. I've set the enclosing row to 
`display: table`
and each column to

```
{ 
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center; 
    margin: auto 0;
}
```

But for some reason, the columns don't center and are left aligned. Can anyone help please? See inserted code.

```css
.bd-centered { 
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center; 
    margin: auto 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="row">
    <div style="display: table;">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 bd-centered">
            <h6 class="text-center breakdown-figures"><span class="glyphicon icon-five text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></span> 70%</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 bd-centered">
            <h6 class="text-center breakdown-figures"><span class="glyphicon icon-four text-success" aria-hidden="true"></span> 10%</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 bd-centered">
            <h6 class="text-center breakdown-figures"><span class="glyphicon icon-three text-muted" aria-hidden="true"></span> 10%</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 bd-centered">
            <h6 class="text-center breakdown-figures"><span class="glyphicon icon-two text-warning" aria-hidden="true"></span> 10%</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 bd-centered">
            <h6 class="text-center breakdown-figures"><span class="glyphicon icon-one text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></span> 20%</h6>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a thought. You could use javascript to dynamically change the bootstrap classes based on the amount of divs you have. Unless you don't want to use javascript of course. (which your tags suggest)  By the way writing class="col-xs-4" does exactly the same as class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4".

Comment: @user1038814 : Check my answer as I believe it holds what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you don't fully understand the bootstrap grid system...
Each row is 12 units wide, and you can divide these up as you choose. For example, in your "5-column layout," you're really doing two rows: each column in the first row is 4 units wide and each column in the second row is 6 units wide.

For the 5-column layout, you can do something like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">...</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">...</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">...</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">...</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">...</div>
```

For the 4-column layout:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">...</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">...</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">...</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">...</div>
```

For the 2-column layout:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">...</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">...</div>
```

Comment: I believe this is the proper way of doing it while not altering or overriding any bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is what you want** [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arifahmedjoy/L2vnn9n7/)
OUTPUT :

```
col1      col2     col3
     col4      col5
```

If there are 4 columns, they should look like this:

```
col1      col2     col3
          col4
```

```css
.bd-centered { text-align: center;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center; 
margin: auto 0;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var elem = $("div.col-lg-4").length;
  switch (elem % 3) {
    case 1:
      $(".table div:nth-child(" + elem + ")").removeClass('col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4').addClass('col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12');
      break;
    case 2:
      $(".table div:nth-child(" + elem + ")").removeClass('col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4').addClass('col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6');
      $(".table div:nth-child(" + (elem - 1) + ")").removeClass('col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4').addClass('col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6');
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row">
<div class="table" style="display: table;">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 bd-centered">
                            <h6 class="text-center breakdown-figures"><span class="glyphicon icon-five text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></span> 70%</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 bd-centered">
                            <h6 class="text-center breakdown-figures"><span class="glyphicon icon-four text-success" aria-hidden="true"></span> 10%</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 bd-centered">
                            <h6 class="text-center breakdown-figures"><span class="glyphicon icon-three text-muted" aria-hidden="true"></span> 10%</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 bd-centered">
                            <h6 class="text-center breakdown-figures"><span class="glyphicon icon-two text-warning" aria-hidden="true"></span> 10%</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 bd-centered">
                            <h6 class="text-center breakdown-figures"><span class="glyphicon icon-one text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></span> 20%</h6>
                        </div>
                        </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```